# ActiveRecord Rails 4, how to look if array attribute contains any of values in array

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Say I have a Book model that has a categories attribute which is an array.
I want to create a scope in which I can grab all Books that contain at least one item from another array I want to pass in.

After googling extensively and trying out many different queries, the closest I've found is this:

```
Book.where("'Mystery' = ANY(categories)")
```

How can I substitute 'Mystery' to be something like `['Categ1', 'Categ2', etc...]` so that I can retrieve any Book that contains AT LEAST ONE of the values in the array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to know three things:

1. PostgreSQL's array overlaps operator: [`&&`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE). `array1 && array2` is true if the two arrays have any elements in common.
2. PostgreSQL's [array constructor syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS), i.e. `array[v1, v2, v3]`.
3. If a placeholder's value is a Ruby array, then ActiveRecord will replace the `?` placeholder with a comma-delimited list so `where('c = any(array[?])', [1,2,3])` will look like `c = any(array[1,2,3])` when it gets to the database.

If you put all those together, you get things like:

```
categories = %w[Categ1 Categ2 Categ3]
Book.where('categories && array[?]', categories)
```

and your scope would be like this:

```
scope :with_any_categories, ->(cats) { where('categories && array[?]', cats) }
```

or perhaps:

```
scope :with_any_categories, ->(*cats) { where('categories && array[?]', cats.flatten) }
```

depending on how you want to use the scope.

Comment: That worked and it's a great answer I didnt even know how to look for those concepts, thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much. I was just looking for this and not only does it solve my problem you also helped grasping some concepts with Rails/Postgres.

Comment: I get `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying[] && text[]`

Comment: @Rob You should be able to add a type cast: `where('categories::text[] && array[?]', ...)` or `where('categories && array[]::varchar[]', ...)`.